# Set test case files for travis

Tags: python, travis-ci, pytest

I have this [project](https://github.com/b5y/log2html) on GitHub which has test case files. I run tests locally via pytest and all passed. But travis does not pass these tests and outputs errors:

`OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/travis/build/b5y/log2html/tests/test_samples'`

I set path to test files this way:

```
DIR_TEST_FILES = os.getcwd() + os.sep + 'tests' + os.sep + 'test_samples'
```

I have tried with `DIR_TEST_FILES = './test_samples'` and with `os` module through `path` method. Nothing works for travis.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow your tests are being run from the log directory inside your build directory. Make sure that travis-ci is in the same directory when it runs tests as you are when you run tests. It may be helpful to include a `pwd` or `ls` in the `script:` section of your `.travis.yml` file initially so that you can determine the relative paths to your tests.

Comment: How can I change directory to project? just `cd log2html` does not work.

Comment: `cd` up out of the directory using `cd ..`